# Java date format pattern

Tags: java

I have problems finding a java date pattern that correctly reads this date from a string:

```
2012-01-17T11:53:40+00:00
```

If the timezone would be standard (+0000), this pattern would work:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
```

but this is not the case. The small `z` doesn't match either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you can use the letter `X` to represent an [ISO 8601 time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone).

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
```

Comment: I'm not using Java 7 but this answer is correct. This is a non standard format and cannot be parsed out of the box (as @Bohemian mentioned). Once Java 7 is used, this will help alot!

Answer (score 6):

Replace the last colon by an empty string, and then parse. Simplest solutions are sometimes the best ones.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a pattern, because your offset is not in the standard format.

However, if you correct the input string, you *can* parse it.
This code works:

```
String input = "2012-01-17T11:53:40+00:00";
input = input.replaceAll(":(..)$", "$1"); // lose the last colon
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to some comments on this page, that input string with an offset of `+00:00` [is indeed in standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC), the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. It is the old date-time classes bundled with early versions of Java that have the problem/limitation.

## java.time

In Java 8 and later, use the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework rather than those old classes.

We have only an offset-from-UTC in your input string, not a [full time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). So we parse this string as a [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

Your input string is already in standard ISO 8601 format, and java.time uses ISO 8601 formats by default, so no need to specify a coded parsing pattern. We can let the `OffsetDateTime` class [parse directly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-). Just one short line of code.

```
String input = "2012-01-17T11:53:40+00:00";
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse ( input );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " odt: " + odt );
```

> input: 2012-01-17T11:53:40+00:00 odt: 2012-01-17T11:53:40Z

Note the `Z` on the end of the output from the `toString` method on a `OffsetDateTime`. That `Z` is short for `Zulu` which means an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero, `+00:00`.

### Assign Time Zone

If you need to, you can adjust this `OffsetDateTime` into a specific time zone, creating a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant ( zoneId );
```

Both the `OffsetDateTime` object and the `ZonedDateTime` object represent the **same moment on the timeline**. The difference is in how an individual person might experience that moment when she looks up at her [office wall to read the clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time). In Montréal she would see "6:53 AM", while her associate in Iceland (which uses UTC time) would see "11:53 AM" if looking up at same simultaneous moment.

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " odt: " + odt + " zdt: " + zdt );
```

> input: 2012-01-17T11:53:40+00:00 odt: 2012-01-17T11:53:40Z zdt: 2012-01-17T06:53:40-05:00[America/Montreal]

Note that java.time extends the ISO 8601 format by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.